# Show that $1+ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} + ... + \frac{1}{p^k} = \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^k(p-1)}$

Tags: prime-numbers, geometric-progressions

I need to show that

$1+ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} + ... + \frac{1}{p^k} = \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^k(p-1)}$ , where $p$ is a prime number.

I have started by doing the following:

$$1 + p^{-1} + p^{-2} + ... p^{-k}  = 1 + (p + p^2 + ... + p^k)^{-1} =  1 + [p(1+p+p^2+...+p^{k-1})] ^{-1}$$

= $$1 + [p(\frac{p^k-1}{p-1})]^{-1} = 1 + \frac {p-1}{p^{k+1}+p} =\frac {p^{k+1} - 1} {p^{k+1} - p}  $$

I have $p$ instead of $p^k$ in the last denominator.

UPD.

Comment: Note that this is a geometric series (finite) not only when $p$ is prime, but whenever $p$ is nonzero.  In your penultimate line you've made a mistake in taking a reciprocal "outside the parentheses".

Comment: Your first guess is wrong.  For instance, $1 + 3^{-1} = \frac43$ is not the same as $(1 + 3)^{-1} = \frac14$

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for induction!

Base case: $k=0$
$$\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^k(p-1)}= \frac{p-1}{p-1}=1 $$
It works so we assume that the identity holds for k $$1 + \frac{1}{p}+... + \frac{1}{p^k} = \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^k(p-1)}$$
And try to prove the identity true for k+1
$$1 + \frac{1}{p}+... + \frac{1}{p^k} + \frac{1}{p^{k+1}} = \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^k(p-1)} + \frac{1}{p^{k+1}} = \frac{p(p^{k+1}-1)+ (p-1)}{p^{k+1}(p-1)}= $$
$$= \frac{p^{(k+1) +1}-1}{p^{k+1}(p-1)} $$
QED 
Notice that nowhere in the proof did I use the fact that p is prime. As long as p is not zero or one (denominator is not zero) the theorem holds.

Answer (score 0):

You might be knowing the sum of GP starting with any number say $a$ with common ratio $r$  and number of terms $n$ is $$\frac {a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$$

In your case $a=1$ , $r=\frac {1}{p}$ , $n=k+1$

Just substitute the values to get the answer.